# Issue with plotting function

Tags: plotting, functions

I can't seem to work out why nothing is showing when I try to plot h[t] in the example below:

```
pL = 1;
fL = 0.1;
eV = 200;
bR = 0.1;
g = 9.81;

m[t_] := pL + (fL - t*bR)
v1[t_] := eV*Log[m[t]/(m[t] - bR*t)] - g*t
h[t_] := Integrate[v1[t], t]
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Try replacing `v1` in `h[t_]` with `v1[t]`.

Comment: Sorry - updated

Comment: Try `h[t_] = Integrate[v1[t], t]` instead.

Comment: Oh it worked when I use = rather than := why is this?

Comment: `h[t_] := Evaluate[Integrate[v1[t], t]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably a duplicate but `Plot` has attributes `HoldAll`. As @J.M. suggested you could use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` (i.e. `=` rather than `:=`) but for some cases that may not be desirable. If you need to use `SetDelayed` you could do the following as a work around:

```
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```