# Why does an expression plot differently if it is pre-evaluated?

Tags: plotting

I am experiencing strange behavior within *Mathematica* when plotting the `InverseLaplaceTransform` of a function. Essentially, I get a different plot when I paste in the result of the `InverseLaplaceTransform` evaluation than I do if I just plot the function that involves the `InverseLaplaceTransform`.

I may not have explained this very well, but hopefully the example code that I have pasted below will clear things up.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, there was a typo in the code. See below. Regardless, the issue is still present.

```
H[s_] := (s + 1)/(s^2 + 5 s + 6)
x[t_] := 3 Exp[-5 t] UnitStep[t]

(* X[s_] := LaplaceTransform[xb2[t], t, s] *)
X[s_] := LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]

Y[s_] := X[s]*H[s]
y[t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[Y[s], s, t]
Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 6}]
y[t]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 6}]
```

If you run this code, you should observe that the two plots are quite different. I was expecting them to be identical, but perhaps I have overlooked something. I have included a screen capture of my results below.

[image: (Updated) Screenshot of my results]

Comment: `xbt` appears to be undefined.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/issue-with-plotting-function/98025#98025

Answer (score 8):

```
H[s_] := (s + 1)/(s^2 + 5 s + 6)
x[t_] := 3 Exp[-5 t] UnitStep[t]
X[s_] := LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]
Y[s_] := X[s]*H[s]

Clear[y]

y[t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[Y[s], s, t]

?y
```

[image]

Since `y` is defined with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) and [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), you need to [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) it within the Plot

```
Attributes[Plot]

(*  {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}  *)

Plot[Evaluate[y[t]], {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define `y` with [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)

```
Clear[y]

y[t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[Y[s], s, t];

?y
```

[image]

Note that the stored definition of `y` is the evaluation of the `InverseLaplaceTransform`

```
Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: @"Bob Hanlon" - I see the result but don't fully understand it. I would think that **not** using `Evaluate` would be extremely slow. I would expect that `InverseLaplaceTransform` would be repeatedly evaluated for each point. Yet I would still expect the answer to be correct. Can you elaborate as to why we actually get an incorrect plot? Thank you

Comment: @JackLaVigne - as shown in the edit above, when `y` is defined with `Set` the stored definition is the evaluated `InverseLaplaceTransform` so the `Plot` is not significantly slowed by not using `Evaluate`. I do not know why the plot is wrong rather than just slowed when `y` is defined with `SetDelayed` and not evaluated within the `Plot`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne The reason for the incorrect `Plot` is that `Plot` effectively uses `Block`. Compare for example `y[1.5]` with `Block[{t = 1.5}, y[t]]`. There is a global `t` in `X`, which also gets effected when `Block` is used.

Comment: @Karten7 - Thank you for the explanation. I think I get it.