# Solving a set of trigonometric equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I've been trying to solve the following equations in order to plot `Subscript[θ, 41]` with respect to `Subscript[θ, 2]` from 0 to 360 degrees.

[image]

```
Subscript[r, 1] = 38.79;
Subscript[r, 2] = 15;
Subscript[r, 3] = 50;
Subscript[r, 41] = 41.5;
Subscript[θ, 1] = 191.6 Degree;

Eq1 = Subscript[r, 1] Cos[Subscript[θ, 1]] == 
        (Subscript[r, 2] Cos[Subscript[θ, 2] \[Degree]] + 
         Subscript[r, 3] Cos[Subscript[θ, 3] \[Degree]] + 
         Subscript[r, 41] Cos[Subscript[θ, 41] \[Degree]])

Eq2 = Subscript[r, 1] Sin[Subscript[θ, 1]] == 
        (Subscript[r, 2] Sin[Subscript[θ, 2] \[Degree]] + 
         Subscript[r, 3] Sin[Subscript[θ, 3] \[Degree]] + 
         Subscript[r, 41] Sin[Subscript[θ, 41] \[Degree]])

Plot[(Subscript[θ, 41] /. 
        NSolve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[θ, 41]}][[2]]) + 360, 
        {Subscript[θ, 2], 0, 360} , PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, {240, 300}}]

Solution = (Subscript[θ, 41] /. 
        NSolve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[θ, 41]}][[2]]) + 360;

Plot[Solution, {Subscript[θ, 2], 0, 360}]
```

The solution of this gives 4 solutions for `Subscript[θ, 41]`.
The problem is, whenever I try to plot one of those solutions by putting the whole `Solve` phrase in the `Plot` statement, it works.
But whenever I try to do them separately, it gives a completely different plot.

More details shown in the following photos:

[image]

The first plot is the one I'm looking for. The second one gives a different plot!... Although I technically haven't done anything different.

I think it's important to mention that I've noticed that the strange plot I got (the second one) is somehow a combination of all 4 solutions. It's typical to a certain solution in a certain range of Theta's, then flips to another solution in another range. I don't know how this helps.

I hope someone would explain this to me, thank you !!

Comment: Please add your code in a copyable format instead or in addition to the picture.

Comment: Possibly the two plots are different due to the fact that `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` or that it effectively is using `Block` for Theta2.

Comment: @Karsten7. I've added my code at the top of my post.

Comment: @Karsten7. The point is, I can't keep plugging in all my Nsolve[] statements in my plots, my code gets messier and I end up using nested Nsolve statements which takes Mathematica ages to plot, I need to save my Theta41 solution somewhere to use it later on instead of having to generate it every time, But as you can see, It doesn't give the same solution when I try to plot it after being saved :/ .. Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: `Subscript[r, 3 ]` is undefined.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @bbgodfrey That probably should be `Subscript[r, 3] = 50`.

Comment: There seems to be other parts of the code missing. Can't reproduce the second plot evaluating the given code.

Comment: @Karsten7.  Agree on both counts.  Moreover, code for two plots look equivalent to me, and I do not understand how the code for the first plot produces anything.

Comment: @Karsten7. Yes I missed that line, apologies i added it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The first plot produces something, because `Subscript[\[Theta], 2]` has a value at every point `Plot` evaluates that `NSolve[...]`. It is very similar to the situation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98831/why-does-an-expression-plot-differently-if-it-is-pre-evaluated/98832#comment268249_98832).

Comment: @Karsten7.You were right about the HoldAll attribute, I tried holding ( Solution ), Then Releasing it inside the plot statement, The output was the same as the initial plot, which is the correct one.
This, though, doesn't solve the problem of the fact that I have to evaluate all of my solve statements inside my plots, It slows down my plotting.

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.