# How does Table behave differently?

Tags: list-manipulation, scoping

I have some functions, that I cannot break down to a reasonable MWE, so I'm going to try for an abstract question without providing the code. If need be, I'll include the extra code.

I have some functions that do some stuff. They seem to work when executed directly. When I put them in a `Plot` it's really slow, because function evaluations can be 1 second each. So I'm making a `Table` of values for a ListLinePlot, which is quicker (I've tried `PerformanceGoal` and `Mesh` and they were all slow). My problem is that I get errors that I cannot reproduce directly/manually. One example is if I run the following code,

```
maxThresh[findQ2[6]]
```

I get,

```
0.172831
```

But if I run,

```
Table[maxThresh[findQ2[q1]], {q1, {6}}]
```

I get,

```
During evaluation of In[702]:= NMinimize::nrnum: The function value -0.00996218+0.113392 I is not a real number at {x} = {0.516997}. >>
```

and a whole bunch more of similar errors. So the direct evaluation worked and gave me the right numerical answer, and the `Table` evaluation gives me an error. I was hoping to gain an understanding as to how these two things are at all different. Does `Table` not simply loop over the values and substitute in for `q1`? There is a subtlety here, because running that function with the value `6` works (btw, it works for most values, but 20% fail with errors like these, that I cannot reproduce if I just execute the function directly).

Still haven't got my head around Mathematica substitutions...

Comment: Possible source of the problem: "`Table` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables."[[documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)]

Comment: Does `Table[maxThresh[findQ2[§q1]], {§q1, {6}}]` work?

Comment: @Karsten7. yes that works! What is this black magic you have introduced me to?

Comment: You are effectively evaluating `Block[{q1 = 6}, maxThresh[findQ2[q1]]]` and all `q1` in every function definition involved potentially gets set to `6`.

Comment: So `Block` gives `q1` a value, even inside functions and modules called inside these functions that have nothing to do with the outside call? And your solution was just to change the name of the variable to something I likely haven't used?

Comment: Dynamic scoping is nasty! Thanks @Karsten7.

Comment: You probably have a global `q1` somewhere in your code, that is not localized to a function. By renaming you avoid that unwanted change of that global `q1`.

Comment: Without a MWE you have to figure out where the problem is yourself. There is an [older question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98831/18476) with a similar problem, but with `Plot`. You can use that as an MWE for yourself and try to understand my [comment there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98831/why-does-an-expression-plot-differently-if-it-is-pre-evaluated/98832#comment268249_98832).

Comment: Syntax highlighting should help to find the problematic `q1`s. If it's blue or black, it's a potential troublemaker.

Comment: I understand now what the problem is, but I don't quite know how to avoid this in future. I might look for best practises or ask another question if I can't find a good answer.

Comment: Take a look at Module

Comment: Changing the name of `q1` in the `Table` to something stupid you definitely would not have used yet, like `aoeu` should tell you immediately if this is the problem.

Comment: The discussion in [(94061)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94061/142) might be useful.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127183/4999