# weird behavior of plot

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Can someone provide an explanation for the following behavior?

I define a function:

```
a=2480.65;
n[x_] := (1/x^2)*1/(Exp[a/x] - 1);
Plot[n[y], {y, 100, 1000}]
Plot[n[a], {a, 100, 1000}]
```

The first plot generates this:

[image: good fig]

while the second one looks like this:

[image: bad fig]

Trivially the first one is correct as this should be a monotonically increasing function.
Is it something in the order of evaluation?
How can I be careful not to stumble upon this point in less easily verified cases?

I'm using MMA 9, with mac

Comment: You've defined your function with a *fixed* parameter $a$ and then try to plot it with a *variable* $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Plot` and `Table` and others "effectively use `Block` to localize variables."
Let's first look at your definition of `n`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that it depends on the (unevaluated!) global symbol `a`.  That means when `a` changes its value, the function changes, too!

[`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) is used to temporarily change the value of a global variable.  Observe the difference:

```
Block[{a = b}, n[a]]
(*  1/(b^2 (-1 + E))  *)

n[a]
(*  9.45746*10^-8  *)
```

In the first case, `a` is changed to `b` and then that is substituted for `x` in expression for `n`.  So both `a` and `x` are changed to `b`. That makes the first code equivalent to

```
(1/b^2)*1/(Exp[b/b] - 1)
```

In the second code, it works as intended, since `a` retains its value of `2480.65`.

The `Plot` command effectively evaluate the first code,

```
Block[{a = x}, n[a]]
(*  1/((-1 + E) x^2)  *)
```

except it does it with numeric values substituted for `x`.  So effectively you're plotting a constant over `x^2`.

To avoid it, you should avoid having your function definitions depend on global variables, whenever possible.  If the global variable is not intended to be a fixed constant, then you should make it an explicit argument of the function. (Such as David Stork has shown while I've been typing.)

```
n[x_, a_] := 1/(x^2 (Exp[a/x] - 1));
```

This is what probably should be done 99% of the time.

Sometimes it is intended to be a constant.  If it is in a package, then it should be in a private context; see [Contexts and Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ContextsAndPackages.html).  Sometimes I'm lazy or the code is temporary, and the constant is a number that appears in several places. In that case, I might use one of the following two ways. First:

```
Block[{x},
 n[x_] = (1/x^2)*1/(Exp[a/x] - 1);
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Second:

```
With[{a = 2480.65`},
 n[x_] := (1/x^2)*1/(Exp[a/x] - 1);
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In both cases, we can see that the value of `a` appears in the exponent.  In the first case the use of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) causes the right-hand side to be evaluated before the definition is stored; that is how the value of `a` is inserted.  In the second, the value is injected with [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html); this rewriting of the rule causes the formal parameter `x` to be renamed `x$`; see, for example, [Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html).  This is to protect the definition from having a value inject for `x` in the pattern `x_`, which would break the definition.

Comment: To summarize, are you saying that whenever I wish to use constants (like physical constants), in my function definition, I should use a construct which would force evaluation of the RHS before storing the definition? Would using the `Function` construct instead of `SetDelayed` for initial definition of the function do the job too (without other workarounds)?

Comment: @YairM `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so the constant `a` would be unevaluated, unless you used `Evaluate`: `Function[x, Evaluate[body]]`. In other words, it has the same problem. Another approach, which you see used by *Mathematica*, is to use long names that are unlikely to be used for simple parameters in `Plot`. I'm sure many users just remember not to use a constant as a variable, but it's a bug waiting to happen. I sometimes start constants with `$` and not variables or functions: `$a = 2480.65`. it's still a lurking bug, but avoidable if I stick to my convention.

Comment: How do I use the private context approach? Should it read ``Private`a=2480``, and then ``n[x_]:=(1/x^2)*(Exp[Private`a/x]-1)^(-1)``?

Comment: @YairM Something like that.  I usually use a lower-case name, like ``const`a``.  By private, I meant a context you make up.  (More often, I use an explicit parameter, `n[x_, a_]` and not the context approach).

Answer (score 1):

You defined a function of a *single* variable, and then try to plot it as a function of a *different* variable.

This seems to be what you're seeking:

```
n[x_, a_] := 1/(x^2 (Exp[a/x] - 1));
 GraphicsColumn[
  {With[{a = 2480.65}, 
    Plot[n[a, y], {y, 100, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "n[2480.65,y]"}]],
   With[{x = 1000}, 
    Plot[n[a, x], {a, 100, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "n[a, 1000]"}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `a` a variable? I defined it before as a constant? when I call a function, i.e. `n[x]`, isn't the argument I call it with treated as a local/temporary variable, regardless of the name I use?

Comment: No.  You defined `n` for a specific value of `a`; you cannot change it thereafter.  To do so, you must make your function a *function* of `a`.  For the same reason you cannot define a function for the perimeter of a circle as $2 \pi r$ and then change $r$ *and then change* $\pi$!